# I have a lower order interaction that becomes significant in the presence of an insignificant higher order interaction

Tags: anova, interaction, interpretation

I have a 5(A)x 3(B) x 2(C) design. When dealing with A and B only, there is a main effect of A and B but not of the interaction of A and B. However adding C in gives a main effect of the interaction of A and B. Specifically, everything is significant, except for the interaction of A, B and C. What does the significance of the interaction of A and B in the full model tell me? Is this more accurate than in the A and B only model where the interaction was insignificant?

Comment: Are there equal Ns in every cell of the design?